# Having Difficulty sending state data on form to different component

Tags: reactjs

I understand that this question has been asked many different times. I've looked through many different ones and I'm still having a difficult time understanding it.
I've read many articles online and I know that I need to pass my state to props and I'm having a difficult time doing so. I managed to pass a simple string of test, however I cannot pass my state to props as it simply returns nothing and I'm not sure why if the values on the form get updated in the onchange method.

I also want to avoid using redux as a alternative as I'm trying to learn the basic way first

What I'm trying to do is very simple, user fills out a box that contains ordernumber on the form. They hit submit, redirects to another page where I'll have access to the ordernum they submitted on the input box for the order number.

Here is my code:

**simple input form page**

```js
/*eslint-disable no-unused-vars*/

import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class Reloform extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            orderNum: "",
            errorMsg: ""
        }
    }

    onChange(e){
        this.setState({
            [e.target.name]: e.target.value
        })
    }

    onSubmit(e){
        if(this.state.orderNum === '') {
            this.setState({
                errorMsg: 'Please enter your order number.'
            });
        } else {
            this.setState({
                errorMsg: ''
            });

            // Submission successful
            window.location = '/relotoForm';

        }
        e.preventDefault();
    }

    render() {
        console.log(this.props)
        return (
            <div className="container">
            
            // I get message prop back but not orderNum?
            <h1>{this.props.message}</h1>
            <h1>{this.props.orderNum}</h1>

                <div className="reloContainer">
                    <form
                        method="POST"
                        id="reloForm"
                        onSubmit={e => this.onSubmit(e)}
                        autoComplete="off"
                    >
                    <h1>T/O Form</h1>
                    {this.state.errorMsg !== '' ? <p style={{color:'#E2231A'}}>Please enter an order number.</p> : ''}
                        <label>Order #</label>
                        <input
                            type="text"
                            name="orderNum"
                            className="form-control"
                            value={this.state.orderNum}
                            onChange={e => this.onChange(e)}
                        />

                        <button type="submit" className="btn btn primary" id="reloButton" onClick={this.props.updateData}>Submit</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Reloform;
```

**/* form action page */**

```js
/*eslint-disable no-unused-vars*/

import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Reloform from './reloForm';

class Relotoform extends React.Component {
    render() {

        return (
            <div>
                //The string that I returned works but the state that I try to have access on this page does not. I am not sure why. My assumption is because maybe this.state is referring to the state of this component and not the form component on my form page?
                <Reloform message="Works" orderNum={this.state.orderNum} />
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Relotoform;
```

Answer (score 1):

State is local to the component you are accessing. If you want to pass a state value to another component, this is where you use props. So when you are trying to render Reloform in your Relotoform component, when you do orderNum={this.state.orderNum}, you won't get any value as there is no state defined for Relotoform in which there's a variable called orderNum.

You need to update the orderNum through your state in the Reloform. You get message displayed because you are passing the value "Works" as a prop in Relotoform. Then you are accessing it correctly as a prop in Reloform. Adapt a similar arhcitecture for orderNum.

Comment: I see. So setstate doesn't simply update the state? Would I need to use a lifecycle method to update the state?

Comment: setState is precisely for that purpose. I believe you have your hierarchy formed incorrectly. If you are rendering Reloform in Relotoform, then you can pass the values from Relotoform to Reloform. You can use props to pass these values and the same to access them in Reloform. As props you could pass hard-coded values or values stored in the state of Relotoform.

Comment: Yes, so when that value changes through the state, then you can pass that value as a prop to the component. So as a prop you could do: 
<Component orderNum={this.state.orderNum} /> . Then in that component you can access that value through props.

Comment: That shouldn't be happening. Could you please show the code you are writing? I have a feeling you aren't implementing it correctly.